# Sending integer across activity showing 0

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

**MainActivity**

```
            ...
            ...
            locationsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.i("ID SENT: ",  toString().valueOf(i));
                mapsIntent.putExtra("number", i );
                startActivity( mapsIntent );
            }
        });
```

**MapsActivity**

```
        ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if ( bundle != null ) {

            int id = getIntent().getIntExtra( "number", 0);
            Log.i("LOCATION MARKED: ", id );
           }
```

Assuming i clicked an item 2 on the list view it shows "ID SENT: 2" on logs but on MapsActivity it shows LOCATION MARKED: 0. Tried different items on list view but still receiving as 0.

**Full code:**

```
        Intent mapsIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = mapsIntent.getExtras();
        if ( bundle != null ) {

            int id = mapsIntent.getIntExtra( "number", 0);
            myLocations = (ArrayList<String>) bundle.getStringArrayList("locations");
            vLoc1 = (ArrayList<String>) bundle.getStringArrayList("loc1");
            vLoc2 = (ArrayList<String>) bundle.getStringArrayList("loc2");
            Log.i("LOCATION MARKED: ", id + " "  + myLocations.get( id ) + " " +  vLoc1.get( id ) + " " + vLoc2.get( id ));
```

**MainActivity( again )**
Yes

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (myLocations.size() > 0 ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("locations", myLocations);
            intent.putExtra("loc1", vLoc1);
            intent.putExtra("loc2", vLoc2);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How have you defined mapsIntent?

Comment: Yes on top.final Intent mapsIntent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class );

Comment: Refer my some Example please i have updated @user3160468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try :*

declare global Intent mapsIntent.

**In main activity :**

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Log.i("ID SENT: ",  toString().valueOf(i));
            mapsIntent = = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            mapsIntent.putExtra("number", i );
            startActivity( mapsIntent );
        }
```

**In pause method :**

```
@Override
        protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (myLocations.size() > 0 ) {
                mapsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("locations", myLocations);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("loc1", vLoc1);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("loc2", vLoc2);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
```

**In maps activity :**

```
Intent mapsIntent = getIntent();
        int id = mapsIntent.getIntExtra("number", 0);
        myLocations = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("locations");
```

Comment: Not working strange thing is 
myLocations = (ArrayList<String>) bundle.getStringArrayList("locations");

seems to be working which is under the code i haven't included that in this post.

Comment: Edited the code as you said and this is how it looks now. 
Intent mapsIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = mapsIntent.getExtras();
        if ( bundle != null ) {
            int id = mapsIntent.getIntExtra( "number", 0);
            myLocations = (ArrayList<String>) bundle.getStringArrayList("locations");
            vLoc1 = (ArrayList<String>) bundle.getStringArrayList("loc1");
            vLoc2 = (ArrayList<String>) bundle.getStringArrayList("loc2");
            Log.i("LOCATION MARKED: ", id + " "  + myLocations.get( id ) + " " +  vLoc1.get( id ) + " " + vLoc2.get( id ));

Comment: Added to main post so it looks less confusing.

Comment: Tried printing and log gives still gives me 0. Just a quick note that string arrays are working only issue is with passing integers.

Comment: Declaring it as global intent seem to work. Thanks maybe i did a lot of declaring intent throughout the code so the global seems to overwrite it all. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3160468 Happy to help :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Change Code in mapsActivity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("number", 0);
```

**write this code in MainActivity**

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.i("ID SENT: ",  toString().valueOf(i));
                Intent mapsIntent = Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
                mapsIntent.putExtra("number", i );
                startActivity( mapsIntent );
            }
        });
```

MapsActivity just after OnCreateMethod

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("number", 0);
Log.i("LOCATION MARKED: ", intValue );
```

Refer this small Example:-

In activity 1:

```
String[] abc;

Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("Your string",abc);
```

In Activity 2 where you want to get give the code as:

```
String abcd[]=bundle.getStringArray("Your string");
```

Comment: Find Updated if it's still not work put your whole code where are you calling this Intent intent = getIntent(); in mapsactivity i need to check that

Comment: StringArrays are working i just added it just to show its working only passing integers got this issue to the other guy who is helping.

Comment: for int use ArrayList<Integer> if you want a list of integer and if you need single value intent has a method getIntExtra